# Convert a project from JDeveloper to Netbeans

Tags: java, jsp, netbeans, struts, jdeveloper

I have an open source project written by JDeveloper , and I want to run this project on Netbeans

**In `struts-config.xml` has the next action :**

```
 <action path="/createFolderLoad"
          type="oracle.adf.controller.v2.struts.actions.DataAction" name="createFolderForm" unknown="false"
          className="oracle.adf.controller.v2.struts.actions.DataActionMapping">
      <set-property property="v1ActionClass"
                    value="com.ccs.dms.folder.action.CreateFolderLoadAction"/>
      <forward name="success" path="/jsp/folder/CreateFolder.jsp"  />
  </action>
```

**and when I run this application the output is :**

```
 Error occurred during deployment: Exception while loading the app : 
 java.lang.IllegalStateException: ContainerBase.addChild: start: 
 org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException:
 javax.servlet.UnavailableException: Parsing error processing resource path jndi:/server/Project_Name/WEB-INF/struts-config.xml.
```

when I remove this action, it runs without any error, so

How can I deal with the `oracle.adf.controller` in Netbeans  IDE?!

Answer (score 1):

The exception occurred when parsing `struts-config.xml` file. The resource should not be JNDI resource, it should be a file resource relative to the web root. Example of configuring web application

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>action</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>
        org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet
    </servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>config</param-name>
        <param-value>
         /WEB-INF/struts-config.xml
        </param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
```

Comment: the configuration file is OK with me and like your example , the problem occure in 'oracle.adf' class , when i remove it it run without any error , but i can't delete this action i need to run it in netbeans